# Looking at a prime sieve program but unsure why it keeps coming up with an error about slice length

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes, sieve

```
def primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]
    print [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

 primes(int(raw_input("Please enter an upper limit ")))
```

The problem occurs on line 5 I know that implementing `[False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)` works but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to replace all elements covered by your slice with **one element**:

```
sieve[i*i::2*i] = [False]
```

That would remove elements from the list, except Python only lets you replace a slice with fewer or more elements if you are not using a stride (it would be allowed if the section was contiguous). Either way, you'd want to replace all those elements with an equal number of elements from the right-hand side, so you can set those positions in the sieve to `False`.

To that end, you'll need to adjust the list on the right-hand side to have enough elements to replace every sliced element:

```
sieve[i*i::2*i] = [False] * (((n - 1 - i*i) // (2 * i)) + 1)
```

The formula calculates how many elements the slice covers in a 0-based indexing system; `n - 1` is the highest index, minus the starting index to give you a number of elements affected, divided by the stride, plus 1 as the stride includes the first element.

Python's `xrange()` object (`range()` in Python 3), makes the [same calculation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ef372f656d1/Objects/rangeobject.c#l15), and includes a longer explanation:

```
Else for step > 0, if n values are in the range, the last one is
lo + (n-1)*step, which must be <= hi-1.  Rearranging,
n <= (hi - lo - 1)/step + 1, so taking the floor of the RHS gives
the proper value.  Since lo < hi in this case, hi-lo-1 >= 0, so
the RHS is non-negative and so truncation is the same as the
floor.
```